# Vertical Nav Menu with Nested ULs displayed horizontally

Tags: html, css

I want to take a ul, display it vertically, but with its nested uls displayed to the right.

The twist: I've already done it. It looks like this:

[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKhnK.png)

But why is the last submenu (Frauke Eigen) so narrow by default? Why can't it let the text expand without wrapping? I want all submenus to have the same width and be positioned next to each other like three equally spaced columns in a table - how can I do that? The best way to do that would be to somehow get the width of .sub1 and pass it along to .sub2, because calc(33%) seems to mean "33% of the parent's width", which will always get smaller.

This is my current code - I've included some HTML so you can see the menu structure...

```
.sub1 {
        width:calc(33%); position:relative;outline: 1px solid black;
    }
    .themenu li>a{
        display:block;background:#eee;
    }
    .sub1 ul {
    }
    .sub2{
        position:absolute; top:0px;left:180px;
        outline: 1px solid black;
    }
    .sub3{
        position:absolute; top: 0px; left:120px;
        outline: 1px solid black;
    }
    .themenu ul ul {
        display: none;
    }

<ul class="sub1">
            <li><a href="#" title="Ausstellungen" >Ausstellungen</a>
                <ul class="sub2">
                    <li><a href="#" title="Aktuell" >Aktuell</a>
                        <ul class="sub3">
                            <li><a href="#" title="Frauke Eigen" >Frauke Eigen</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Vorschau" >Vorschau</a>
                        <ul class="sub3">
                            <li><a href="#" title="Andrew Chiw" >Andrew Chiw</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Archiv" >Archiv</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The way your HTML is set up the only way to have them be the same with is if the children are outside of the parent. To do that they have to have `position:absolute`

Answer (score 0):

You are defining your overall container .sub1 as 33% but you haven't defined anything else. All if the Children are going to inherit that width. 33% smaller each time as it looks in your example. Especially if your nav items are going to be absolute you need to give them a width otherwise the ul will only fill 33% of its container or parent. Hope that helps

Comment: What else should I define for .sub1?

Comment: What about trying something like this. I tested it and it looks to achieve what you are looking for. You may just have to play with the widths to fit your style. Please let me know if that helps.

.sub1 {
        width:33%;
  margin-right:20px;
  outline:1px solid red;
  background:#CCC;
    }
    .sub1 ul {
  float:right;
  outline:1px solid yellow;
  background:#CCC;
    }
    .sub2{
       width:60%;
    }
    .sub3{
  background:#FFF;
  width:50%;
    }